# Nmodbus returns NotImplementedException: Function code 123 not supported exception while reading response data

Tags: c#, modbus

I'm trying to create a modbus reader app using [NModbus](https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus) Library but when connected to port it throws following **error**:

```
System.NotImplementedException: Function code 123 not supported.
at Modbus.IO.ModbusRtuTransport.ResponseBytesToRead(Byte[] frameStart)
at Modbus.IO.ModbusRtuTransport.ReadResponse[T]()
at Modbus.IO.ModbusTransport.UnicastMessage[T](IModbusMessage message)
at Modbus.Device.ModbusMaster.PerformReadRegisters(ReadHoldingInputRegistersReques t request)
at Modbus.Device.ModbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(Byte slaveAddress, UInt16 
startAddress, UInt16 numberOfPoints)
at ModbusReaderSnippet.Program.Main(String[] args).
```

here is snippet of my **code**:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the com port :");
    string comPort = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter slave id :");
    byte slave = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter starting register number :");
    ushort startRegister = Convert.ToUInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter no. of registers to read :");
    ushort noOfRegisters = Convert.ToUInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    bool flag = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter baud rate : ");
    int baud = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    try
    {
        while (flag)
        {

            SerialPort port = new SerialPort(comPort.ToUpper());
            port.BaudRate = baud;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.ReadTimeout = 500000000;
            port.WriteTimeout = 500000000;
            Console.WriteLine("Opening port");
            if (port.IsOpen == true)
            {
                port.Close();
                port.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                port.Open();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Opened port : {0}", comPort.ToUpper());
            IModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);


            byte slaveId = slave;
            ushort startAddress = startRegister;
            ushort numRegisters = noOfRegisters;

            ushort[] registers = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, numRegisters);

            for (int j = 0; j < numRegisters; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Register {0} = {1} of Slave{2}", startAddress + j, registers[j], slaveId);
            }
            port.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue ? Y/N");
            string perm = Console.ReadLine();
            flag = perm == "Y" || perm == "y" ? true : false;
            if (perm == "Y" || perm == "y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter slave id : ");
                slave = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

when I try to read registers `3961` to `3971` or any other registers it gives above error.

I looked up in Nmodbus library and found that response received from meter at 9600 baud rate isn't available in `switch case` statement in `Modbus.IO.ModbusRtuTransport.ResponseBytesToRead(Byte[] frameStart)` method which reads response and sends the register values back.

**Question**: what could I do to get over this problem. At 2400 baud rate port opened but won't poll any values.

Comment: Why not to open an issue on github?

Comment: @vasily.sib Okay I'll give it a try.